# How linux drive many network cards with the same driver?

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I am learning linux network driver recently, and I wonder that if I have many network cards in same type on my board, how does the kernel drive them? Does the kernel need to load the same driver many times? I think it's not possible, insmod won't do that, so how can I make all same kind cards work at same time?

regards

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The state of every card (I/O addresses, IRQs, ...) is stored into a driver-specific structure that is passed (directly or indirectly) to every entry point of the driver which can this way differenciate the cards. That way the very same code can control different cards (which means that yes, the kernel only keeps one instance of a driver's module no matter the number of devices it controls).

For instance, have a look at `drivers/video/backlight/platform_lcd.c`, which is a very simple LCD power driver. It contains a structure called `platform_lcd` that is private to this file and stores the state of the LCD (whether it is powered, and whether it is suspended). One instance of this structure is allocated in the `probe` function of the driver through `kzalloc` - that is, one per LCD device - and stored into the platform device representing the LCD using `platform_set_drvdata`. The instance that has been allocated for this device is then fetched back at the beginning of all other driver functions so that it knows which instance it is working on:

```
struct platform_lcd *plcd = to_our_lcd(lcd);
```

`to_our_lcd` expands to `lcd_get_data` which itself expands to `dev_get_drvdata` (a counterpart of platform_set_drvdata) if you look at `include/linux/lcd.h`. The function can then know the state of the device is has been invoked for.

This is a very simple example, and the `platform_lcd` driver does not directly control any device (this is deferred to a function pointer in the platform data), but add hardware-specific parameters (IRQ, I/O base, etc.) and you get how 99% of the drivers in Linux work.

Comment: Thanks very much, I know how to add more than one same devices in the kernel, just increase the platform_device struct's id, 0,1,2 etc, now the driver can detect these devices well.

Comment: For platform devices, yes - and you can also set id to -1 to specify there is can be only one instance of the device in the system (Linux will then omit the ID when printing the device name to reflect that). Be aware that platform_devices are particular and that other buses may work in a different way, e.g. by identifying devices through their addresses instead of a number.

Answer (score 4):

The driver code is only loaded once, but it allocates a separate context structure for each card.  Typically you will see a `struct pci_driver` with a `.probe` function pointer.  The probe function is called once for each card by the PCI support code, and it calls `alloc_etherdev` to allocate a network interface with space for whatever private context it needs.