# How can 2 wireless interfaces be handled by single carl9170 device driver module

Tags: driver, device

I want to understand the performance of one device driver module in linux kernel. In this case I use **carl9170** device driver in linux.

1. If I use two physical interfaces, how can the single module carl9170 handle 2 different physical interfaces?

   Because so far, I have known that these 2 physical interfaces will make 2 instances and use different packet buffers for each but just using single carl9170 module. So it's confusing me.
2. And which file in linux kernel source code can I find about this handling method (relates to carl9170 device driver)?

Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 2, take a look at the folder:

`drivers/net/wireless/ath/carl9170/`

This folder is located under your kernel source directory. It contains all the sources of the driver.

For 1:

It is pretty much how classes works on oriented object programming: how does an object know which instance of the data it must work with? The `this` pointer references the correct in memory data.

Take a look at the file `drivers/net/wireless/ath/carl9170/carl9170.h`. Every function exported by the driver is declared at this file. Note that every function has at its first parameter a reference to the `struct ar9170` data type. This is exactly the data set that the driver must work with. It specifies everything the driver need to know about the device and its sates, since the USB buses address where the device is connected, to the state of the device, like its power, connection state and any other data the driver itself need in order to keep the device working properly.

Note that this is driver internal data thought. The kernel has its own set of data to keep both the driver, the device and the kernel itself working.

Take a look at the 546 line of [carl9170.h](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git/tree/drivers/net/wireless/ath/carl9170/carl9170.h?id=refs/tags/v3.8.8). It is where the function declarations starts. This file is as of the kernel 3.8.8.

Just like in Object Oriented Programming you would allocate as many instances of a class as you need, the kernel will allocate as many `ar9170` structures a it needs, one referencing each device.

The device ids can be obtained under the `/sys/class/net` directory. There will be a soft link for each of the network devices attached to your computer. This link will point the device to something like the following:

```
$ ls -l eth0
../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:04.0/0000:02:00.0/net/eth0
```

The `pci0000:00` is the bus. The `0000:00:04.0` I believe is the bus address. Finally, the `0000:02:00.0` is the device id. Afaik, every registered device follows the same logic.

Finally, if you have two `carl9170` devices, both will be under the directory `/sys/class/net` but probably one of them will be named `wifi0` and the other `wifi1`. Also, each of them will point to different devices (check it with the command `ls -l /sys/class/net`).

I just would like to note that in the explanation I haven't used any wireless card. So I'm not sure whether wireless cards are shown under `/sys/class/net` or not. Anyway, it will be something very similar, like `/sys/class/wireless`.

Comment: I found about this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8490210/how-linux-drive-many-network-cards-with-the-same-driver. Maybe it relates to no.1 but I still don't understand yet. If you understand about this thread, can you share it with me in simple way? Thank you so much

Comment: @user2290560 It is exactly what that question points out. I'll update my answer.

Comment: It means that if I use 2 physical interfaces that using same device driver, in this case carl9170, will it make 2 instances? and in which file can I differentiate this 2 physical interfaces (like device id,etc) that use same device driver module? Thank you for your answers

Comment: @user2290560 Exactly! I will edit again my answer to complete the explanation.

Comment: @user2290560 if you are having any trouble with some device powered by this driver, take a look at this page (it might help): http://linuxwireless.org/en/users/Drivers/carl9170

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation. It helps me. I found like this : ../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.1/1-1.1:1.0/net/wlan1 Do you know in which file in kernel source can I find about /sys/class/ieee80211 directory? Because I just found that ieee80211 folder contains important information about the device

Comment: @user2290560 The ieee80211 is related to the `lib80211.ko` and `cfg80211.ko` kernel modules. The source code for both modules is found at `net/wireless/` and `include/net/`. There is some device dependent code that is stored at the correspondent device driver source code directory.

Comment: @user2290560 I would like to ask you to accept the answer if it is what you were expecting (as an answer for your question, of course). Also (couldn't expect less), feel free to keep asking related stuff in this and any other thread you may find appropriated.