# How to assign different drivers to NICs which are of the same types in Linux

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver

I have 5 e1000e NICs in my system, and I want 3 of them to load default e1000e driver while 2 of them to use a modified e1000e driver which is made by myself.
How can I do this? Code is preferred if you can provide any.

Comment: He says: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8497529/196561 that there is only single instance of driver per device type, so it is impossible to use 2 e1000e. You should integrate your changes into single module and then use different internal paths for different cards.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it seems that I should look into the code and drivers more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by *unbinding* a device instance from a driver and then *bind* it to another driver. Read the following article:

https://lwn.net/Articles/143397/

This is also useful when your device is assigned to the wrong driver